# Conditional visibility Lottie animation in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

How can I make a lottie animation display each time I click on a button(container)?
I have a page with a stack widget and some other widgets inside it. I'm trying to make a lottie animation conditionaly visible each time the user click on a container.

I tried creating a page state variable "animationshown" as boolean. Set it to false default. On my hide show Lottie animation, I turned on conditional visibility, added the variable. Then in an action on my container, I made it set the value to true. but the animation was shown only the first time I click the button and not te other time. maybe it needs to reset to its default value (false) after the animation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
onTap: () {
 setState(() {
 animationshown = !animationshown 
 });
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?